# Assertion is failing with , An instance name is not a legal rvalue [7.1(IEEE)]

Tags: system-verilog, system-verilog-assertions

My assertion code is as below :

```
property p_crossbar_halted_chk12;
      @(posedge `SOG_REST_SCOPE.clk)
      $rose(`SOG_REST_SCOPE.crossbar_halted) 
          |-> ##[0:1] $rose(`SOG_REST_SCOPE.last_cycle) 
          |-> ##[0:1] $fell(`SOG_REST_SCOPE.last_cycle);
endproperty

ASSERT_P_CROSSBAR_HALTED_CHK12: assert property(p_crossbar_halted_chk12);
```

And it keeps giving compilation error saying

> ASSERT_P_CROSSBAR_HALTED_CHK12 assert property(p_crossbar_halted_chk12) An instance name is not a legal rvalue [7.1(IEEE)]

Comment: This code compiles. The error must be elsewhere. My guess is that there is an instance in the same scope with the instance name `p_crossbar_halted_chk12`.

Answer (score 0):

This happens to me when I try to substitute a %s in a $sformatf call with a macro like yours. Try to give the absolute path in place of your macro '`SOG_REST_SCOPE' and I think the problem will be solved.